# C# Generics issue: some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, generics, arguments

```
public class ImgBuffer<T>
{
    public T[] buf;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public ImgBuffer () {}
    public ImgBuffer (int w, int h)
    {
        buf = new T[w*h];
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void Mirror()
    {
        ImageTools.Mirror (ref buf, width, height);
    }
}
```

And the ImageTools class has Mirror defined for byte[], short[], and Color32[] on the fist argument. In particular:

```
public void Mirror(ref Color32[] buf, int width, int height) { ....
```

But I get this error:

error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `ImageTools.Mirror(ref Color32[], int, int)' has some invalid arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does ImageTools have a Mirror overload on `string[]`? Because I totally want to make a `ImgBuffer<string>`. I'll follow that up with an `ImgBuffer<DateTime>`.

Comment: Then how will the compiler know that a call to Mirror with a string array is legal?

Comment: Is this a joke? Am I using a string array? Color32 is a 4-byte structure (red, green, blue, alpha). I need various image (pixel) formats, with similar functionality.

Comment: No, it was actually not a joke. The compiler doesn't know that T will only by byte, short, or Color32. As far as the compiler is concerned, T *could be* string, DateTime. Those calls are not legal, and therefore you get your error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you expect C# generics to be something like a template. That's not the case. From your description, it appears there is an ImageTools class that looks something like this

```
public class ImageTools
{
    public static void Mirror(ref byte[] buf, int width, int height) { }
    public static void Mirror(ref Color32[] buf, int width, int height) { }
    public static void Mirror(ref short[] buf, int width, int height) { }
}
```

And you have an ImgBuffer class that looks like this (abbreviated)

```
public class ImgBuffer<T>
{
    public T[] buf;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public void Mirror()
    {
        ImageTools.Mirror(ref buf, width, height);
    }
}
```

The compiler cannot verify in `ImgBuffer.Mirror` that the call to `ImageTools.Mirror` is legal. All the compiler knows about `ref buf` is that it is of type `T[]`. The `T` could be anything. It could be string, int, DateTime, Foo, etc. The compiler is unable to verify that the arguments are correct, and therefore your code is illegal.

*This* would be legal, but I have a feeling that you have specific implementations for your Mirror methods for your 3 desired types, so it's probably not workable.

```
public class ImageTools<T>
{
    public static void Mirror(ref T[] buf, int width, int height) { }
}
```

Comment: I see. Yes this is my first foray into C# generics, I was a C++ template guy before. Thank you. So is there a way to fix this without defining a Mirror for every conceivable data type? Casting or constraints?

Comment: Constraints will not work for you here. Constraints can be applied to limit T to a struct or a class, to an interface or given base class, to items with parameterless constructors. You cannot limit them to say "I want T to be byte, short, or Color32."

Comment: Right. I could rework the ImageTools class to be generic, but it needs to perform well (each of these operations is currently optimized for its particular data type. For example, mirroring a short just swaps shorts, but mirroring a Color32 needs to move (in essence) a 4-byte long) Can I detect which type is 'coming in' and switch algorithms?

Comment: I would probably go for some regular, old-fashioned polymorphism and just have a ByteImageBuffer, ShortImageBuffer, Color32ImageBuffer, but I don't know enough about your problem. Generics do not appear to be the right answer. Even if you went with generic ImageTools class, you could *try* to use it with any given T, which doesn't seem to fit your design. You could do `(if typeof(T) == typeof(byte))` to switch algorithms, but that is also messy.

Comment: Forever will it dominate your destiny.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope your generic type argument. For example:

```
public class ImgBuffer<T> where T : Color32
{
    public T[] buf;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public ImgBuffer () {}
    public ImgBuffer (int w, int h)
    {
        buf = new T[w*h];
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void Mirror()
    {
        ImageTools.Mirror (ref buf, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: As Anthony Pegram has correctly inferred, I need this to work for several classes, and listing Color32, short, byte etc. does not work (compiler always says the last class in the list must come first)